# How to read HTML (for email body) from another file in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, html-email

I am new to NodeJS.
I started working on a contact us page, which, when submitted, sends out an acknowledgement email with following HTML to user.

```
<p>Hello Sujit,</p>
<p>Thank you for approaching us.</p>
<p>We have received your request and our executive will get in touch with you soon.</p>
<p>Thank you.</p>
```

Following is the code to send email:

```
var mailer = require("nodemailer");

var emailBody = "<HTML above>";

// Use Smtp Protocol to send Email
var smtpTransport = mailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
    service: "#######",
    auth: {
        user: "#########",
        pass: "#######"
    }
});

var mail = {
    from: "######################",
    to: params.email,
    subject: "Welcome user.",
    text: "",
    html: emailBody
}

smtpTransport.sendMail(mail, function(error, response){
    if(error){
        console.log("Mail error:>>");
        console.log(error);
    }else{
        console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
    }

    smtpTransport.close();
});
```

Currently, using nodemailer, I am sending this email with the HTML body defined in the same file - app.js. It is working fine so far.
But, is there any way I can separate the HTML with variables/placeholders for "name" and place in some other file, so that the body content can be managed directly? Some way by which I can load the body content into the variable `emailBody`.

Thanks.

Comment: Node has many modules available for templating.

Comment: https://nodemailer.com/2-0-0-beta/templating/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes!!  Create one folder with name "templates" inside that create text files for particular email. Like welcome.txt. In welcome.txt write code like

```
<p>Hello #name,</p>
<p>Thank you for approaching us.</p>
```

Then using fs module you can read that file like fs.readFile([filepath]) and store this value in variable . Like var mailContent = fs.readFile([filepath]). Then using javascript replace function replace #name with actual name .
Like mailContent.replace('#name','abcd')

Comment: For bigger applications and for bigger HTML emails, using nodemailer's templates would be useful, but for such small purpose, this solution would work. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can maintain a JSON structure with key value pair.

template.json

{

"Subject" : "Acknowledgement Mail",

"Body" : Above HTML

}

And then you can read require this JSON or pass this as a parameter to your function.

var template = require('./templates.json);

var mail = {

```
from: "######################",
to: params.email,
subject:template.Subject,
text: "",
html: template.Body
```

}

Comment: I don't think this is good approach to do this. If HTML is kept into separate file, UI person can easily make changes there, as it will be a fairly formatted HTML.

Comment: Yeah Sure, Well this differs with the requirement. This approach helps when you have multiple templates to be configured on the fly. And with this, you can have all templates and subject configuration in JSON where mapping of HTML and subject can be configurable at the same place.